# How to get index of specific location in IDL

Tags: spatial-index, idl

I am trying to get the index of specific lat and lon in IDL.

I know how to do it in python.

```
tmp = tmp.sel(lat=lat_loc,lon=lon_loc,method='nearest')
```

But I can't find a way to do so in IDL.

Any suggestion or idea?